# Get router path on NavigationStart of on going navigation angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

How to get router path on NavigationStart event in angular 8

```
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart))
      .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
         // how to get router path of on going navigation
      });
```

I could use event.url, but my application has some of the named outlet, url is mixed of opened named outlet. so looking to find router path of ongoing navigation on NavigationStart.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivatedRoute instead of Router

You may subscribe `url` observable and join segments or use `snapshot`.
It is well documented here.

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#properties

Comment: Thanks Sunil, If i understand correct ActivatedRoute is one time thing and works on specific component.. i am looking to implement application wide logic which gets on going navigation router path on NavigationStart event, my intention is this should execute on any navigation change in application.

Answer (score 0):

Inject both the `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` services.

When the navigation starts, traverse the activated route to find the outlet.

You can use the following code as a starting point.

```
this.router.events
    .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map(activatedRoute => {
            while (activatedRoute.firstChild !== null) {
                activatedRoute = activatedRoute.firstChild
            }

            return activatedRoute
        }),
        filter(activatedRoute => activatedRoute.outlet === "primary"),
        mergeMap(activatedRoute => activatedRoute.url),
    )
```

**Note:** This code will work even if you write it in your root component. The activated route doesn't only denote the route for a particular component that injected it. An activated route represents the entire route tree that led up to your current route.

In your root component activated route is a reference to the route that activated the component i.e. "/". However, you can travel down the route tree to visit other routes (if any).

Similarly, in other components the activated route is a reference to the route that activated that component. But you can traverse up and down to visit other routes.

Comment: Thanks Tuhin, this is somewhat near to what i was looking for.. problem is i have one primary outlet and 2 named outlet.. i should look for named outlet routes also.. it was becoming little problematic to to watch them.. so i ended up using location.onUrlChange here i have more control over what was previous URL and easy to get what are the new changes.